# Use emacsclient as $EDITOR for zsh edit-command-line

Tags: emacsclient, zsh

I have `emacsclient` set as my `$EDITOR`. Yet, when I invoke the zsh function `edit-command-line` (`C-x C-e`) from Terminal I briefly see the Emacs frame open but then it closes immediately. How can I use `emacsclient` as the `$EDITOR` for `edit-command-line`?

Here is my how my `$EDITOR` variable is set: `export EDITOR='emacsclient -t -c '`

Here is my zsh config: `bindkey '\C-x\C-e' edit-command-line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Emacs seems to have resolved this issue.